# Visual C++ Linker: Define order of symbols (variables) or define new section for .data <common>

Tags: visual-c++, linker, sequence, symbols, sections

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I have following problem to solve:

The symbol (variable) 'Start_Common' should be the first variable of the `<common>` part of the .data section like

```
0003:000932d4       __umaskval                 1057a2d4     libucrtd:umask.obj
0003:000932e0       __fmode                    1057a2e0     libucrtd:txtmode.obj
>>> 0003:000932e4       _Start_Common              1057a2e4     <common>  
0003:000932e8       _VARCODE_STATE             1057a2e8     <common>
0003:00093300       _VAR_COPY_EEPROM_DB_PARAM  1057a300     <common>
```

(the line beginning with '>>>' was manuelly inserted by my)

Is there a way to do this?

Or can I assign a new section name to the `<common>` section (e.g. .common) which would be result in:

```
 0003:00000000 0002c910H .data                   DATA
 0003:0002c910 00001fd4H .data$r                 DATA
 0003:0002e900 0007ba1cH .bss                    DATA
>>> 0003:0002e900 0007ba1cH .common                    DATA (same section 0003 like .data)
```

or

```
 0003:00000000 0002c910H .data                   DATA
 0003:0002c910 00001fd4H .data$r                 DATA
 0003:0002e900 0007ba1cH .bss                    DATA
>>> 0004:00000000 0007b000 .common                    DATA (new section 0004)
```

(the line beginning with '>>>' was manuelly inserted by my)

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You might be looking for this: [Using linker segments and __declspec(allocate(…)) to arrange data in a specific order](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=100155)

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks a lot for your response. But this is what I know allready. The problem is, that there are about thousands of files which I am not allowed to edit (no __declspec(allocate(...)) adding possible). All variables (about 20000) of this files are merged to the ``common``-part of the .data - section. My only chance I see, is to give an  own section-name to the ``common``-part or try to understand how the order within the ``common`` section can be manipulated. You have any idea?

Comment: No, I don't know any other ways to manipulate the order within the section. Why do you want to do that? What are you really trying to achieve? Why does the order within section matter? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hi Igor, so I solved the problem. It is a little bit tricky and a hack. But so far as I understand, the sort order of the elements of a section (or a part of it) depends on the sort order of the path and the object-name combined with the sort order of the ClCompile- elements within the vcxproj-file combined with the reversed sort order of the first reference (not occurrence) of a symbol. Took a long time to find it out. :-(